# Steps involved in Dynamic Programming algorithm development

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

How Dynamic Programming Development is performed. Are there any detailed steps that are involved in performing the dynamic programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The seven steps in the development of a dynamic programming algorithm are as follows:

1- Establish a recursive property that gives the solution to an instance of the problem.

2- Develop a recursive algorithm as per recursive property

3- See if same instance of the problem is being solved again an again in recursive calls

4- Develop a memoized recursive algorithm

5- See the pattern in storing the data in the memory

6- Convert the memoized recursive algorithm into iterative algorithm

7- Optimize the iterative algorithm by using the storage as required (storage optimization)